# How can I use mm-yy format with datepicker?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, format

I'm starting with javascript and I have a little problem with the datepicker. I have an object created which select a date from a panel (with format mm-yy). The problem is that if I write a date manually it doesn't save that data and puts the default one in the displayed calendar. I need to define the date both from the calendar and by written in the text box. This problem doesn't occur when the format is dd-mm-yy, but I need the mm-yy format. Thank you!

The code is:

```
$(function() {
    $('.calendar').datepicker( {
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'mm-yy',
        onClose: function(selectedText, inst) {
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Which datepicker are you using?

Comment: There’s more than one?

Comment: Yes, there is a bunch of them. So, which one?

Comment: Sorry, but I have only found information about the .datepicker used in the code that I show you.

Comment: You don't know the library you use?

Comment: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html, this?

Answer (score 0):

Date from calendar

```
$(function() {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker( {
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            onClose: function(dateVal) {
             var ym = dateVal.substring(3);
             document.getElementById("datepicker").value = ym;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, it is a good approach but it does not help me since I need the onclose to save the information like this:

$ (this) .datepicker ('setDate', new Date (inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));

The mm-yy format would be only for what is reflected in the datepicker panel on the page.

Comment: So you want that the datepicker show you only moth and year in datepicker panel?